# Rails Server Wont' Start Syntax Error in Config/Initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just begun working with Rails and I have come to start up my server for the second time, but I get the following error message? I have not modifed any Ruby files in /config/initializers either.

```
george@ubuntu:~/Desktop/blog$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/george/Desktop/blog/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'
                              ^
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/george/Desktop/blog/config/environment.rb:5
    from /home/george/Desktop/blog/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/george/Desktop/blog/config.ru:4
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/george/Desktop/blog/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/george/Desktop/blog/config.ru:1
```

The contents of config/initializers/session_store is below.

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Blog::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
# Blog::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Comment: can you get the contents of session store.rb in your config/initializers?

Comment: It seems to be throwing the errors for each Ruby script in config/initializers.


`# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

    Blog::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'

    # Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
    # which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
    # (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
    # Blog::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're running ruby version 1.8. You need to upgrade to 1.9.

The `key: 'value'` Hash syntax is not supported by ruby 1.8 (where it needs to be `:key => 'value'`).

If that's not an option, you could manually change all those hashes, but be aware that Rails support for ruby 1.8 is running out.

Comment: I will reinstall Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM and set it to be the default. I will let you know on my progres.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ruby 1.9.3 and all is working great! Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark, and do so for you other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try Blog::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_blog_session'